# Contains a string in a cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do conditional highlighting in Excel that would highlight the entire row of a cell if the cell contains a string.

Say I would like to determine if the cell contains the word "done". The cell can contain such text and would still be able highlight the cell:

1. done
2. It is done
3. abcdone

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting yet? https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-cells-that-contain

Comment: @BigBen conditional formatting only applies to a cell. I would need to do a custom formula to highlight the entire row

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("done",$A1))`.

Comment: Conditional formatting can "Apply to:" a range of cells and use the same formula.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen It works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my example data set:

[image]

The conditional formatting window looks like this:

[image]

The rule applies to =$A$2:$D$13 (entire data table except for the header row)
The base formula used is =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))

Don't forget to make an absolute reference to the cell containing the search word (substring). For the *text*, make sure the column has an absolute reference starting in the top-left corner of first data entry, and rows have a relative reference (this is already done in the formula shown above, but I'm just elaborating on it here in general in case you do something similar in the future)